# How can I download the latest build job artifact from Gitlab CE (self-hosted) using curl?

Tags: curl, gitlab, gitlab-api, gitlab-ce

My local server install of Gitlab is currently version 15.3.0. I have created a personal access token (selected all scopes) and identified the URL to download the artifacts.zip file (works in browser when logged in to Gitlab).

But, when I try this with curl, I always get a redirect to the login page:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" "http://myserver/emu/myproject/-/jobs/artifacts/main/download?job=build"
```

.. results in ..

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://myserver/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

And, of course, adding the `-L` parameter gets me the HTML markup of the login page instead of the artifact I want. I also verified that the token works by calling the API like so:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" "http://myserver/api/v4/projects"
```

That gives me the project list in JSON format as expected.

I know that there are some restrictions on the free edition of Gitlab such as JOB-TOKEN not being available. But I found no indication in the docs that would suggest that the artifact download using the personal access token requires a paid edition:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use
`curl -L --output artifacts.zip --location --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <YOUR_TOKEN>" "<YOUR_SERVER>/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/jobs/artifacts/main/download?job=<BUILD_JOB_NAME>"`
I hope that solves your issue